# about cardinal ，mapping on X

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

if A is a infinite set ，define B={f|f is 1-1 correspondence on A}

I want to compute Card(B)

My attempt when A is finite ,then card(B)=$2^{card(A)}-2$

Such as A={$a_1,a_2$},then there exist two function f:$f(a_1)=a_2,f(a_2)=a_1$

$g:g(a_1)=a_1,g(a_2)=a_2$

So I guess when A is infinite ,card(B)=$2^{card(A)}$,but I can’t proof it can someone help me

Comment: When A is finite, there are (#A)! bijections from A to A.

Comment: what is（#A）！means?  And my question is when A is infinite ..

Comment: To the proposer: By (# A) he means the number of members of A. Set-theorists often use |A|. And n! means n-factorial.

Comment: i can’t understand the duplicate question’s answer...